# Turn matrix into column-wise new flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm working with an array of arrays, and each inner array contains objects.

I would like to reorganise this array to a flat array, where the order is column-wise (see below).

Currently I have written this:

```
const newArray = [];

arr.map((rows, i) => {
  rows.map((row) => {
     newArray.splice(i, 0, row);
    });
  });
```

But the order starts going wrong further into the operation.

(For note I'm using a Promise library inside of Node so treat the maps as normal maps)

#### Current Array

```
const arr = [
  [
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_1: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_2: '-', item_3: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_4: '-', item_5: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_6: '-', item_7: '-' }
  ],
  [
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_1: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_2: '-', item_3: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_4: '-', item_5: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_6: '-', item_7: '-' }
  ],
  [
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_1: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_2: '-', item_3: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_4: '-', item_5: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_6: '-', item_7: '-' }
  ]
]
```

#### Expected Array

```
const arr = [
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_1: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_1: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_1: '-' },
   
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_2: '-', item_3: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_2: '-', item_3: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_2: '-', item_3: '-' },
   
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_4: '-', item_5: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_4: '-', item_5: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_4: '-', item_5: '-' },
  
    { Mapped_Index: 'Alignment', item_6: '-', item_7: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Autonomy', item_6: '-', item_7: '-' },
    { Mapped_Index: 'Belonging', item_6: '-', item_7: '-' }
]
```

Comment: what's the point of using promises here?

Comment: This is a small part of a larger code base, ignore the maps. @georg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to *transpose* the original matrix, and then flatten that:

```
let result = arr[0].flatMap((_, i) => arr.map(row => row[i]));
```

Comment: Thank you, i've not used `flatMap()` often so this is great

Answer (score 0):

First step: merge the array of arrays of objects to an array of objects:

```
var merged = [].concat.apply([], arr);
```

Second step: Sort objects by `Mapped_Index`

```
function compare( a, b ) {
    if ( a.Mapped_Index < b.Mapped_Index ){
        return -1;
    }
    if ( a.Mapped_Index > b.Mapped_Index ){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

merged.sort(compare);
```

Sorting by the field-names as a third step is a little tricky.